# How to Integrate Linkedin in Android Application?

Tags: android, api, linkedin-api

I have to integrate linked in my android application. Can someone suggest me some framework. 
https://github.com/mdinacci/linkedin-for-android/downloads
i used this link but not working. Any example will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is over a year old. However, if you search on Google this question keeps coming up in the results. That's why I felt the need to provide another answer.

I found a nice library called socialauth-android exists to easily integrate the 10 popular social networks (Facebook, Twitter, MySpace, LinkedIn etc).

I have just checked its latest version(2.0) and it seems that it solved Linkedin new keys bugs which I faced earlier and now I am able to share status , get contacts and get user profile.

Please see [socialauth-android](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/) website

Comment: ur link not shown jobtitle so its just integrate app but not get whole data

Answer (score 1):

The LinkedIn [Libraries and Tools](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/libraries-and-tools) page has an [Android Library](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/) listed.

It's actively developed (has groups and companies, two of the newest resources) was updated in September, and has good feedback on the forums.

I'd probably start there for Android development.